# Pycharm Startup will not connect to console

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am trying to start up pycharm and am getting the following error while connecting to the console:

```
C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=52061
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\envs\Base\Lib\site.py", line 579, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\envs\Base\Lib\site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\envs\Base\Lib\site.py", line 349, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\envs\Base\Lib\site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\envs\Base\Lib\site.py", line 159, in addpackage
    f = open(fullname, "r")
  File "C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\envs\Base\Lib\_bootlocale.py", line 12, in getpreferredencoding
    if sys.flags.utf8_mode:
AttributeError: 'sys.flags' object has no attribute 'utf8_mode'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am making a transition from spyder to pycharm and am currently experiencing a lot of problems most notable this one. I have set up the correct project interpreter.

Comment: Python 2 does not have a `sys.flags.utf8_mode` and throws that error when you try to access it. Python 3 should be able to access it no problem. Are you sure that you set the correct interpreter? Did you install packages for the wrong Python version?

Comment: I get the same error, after I uninstalled Python 3.6, which I did after installing Python 3.7. I was already using Python 3.7 through Pycharm successfully for a while, so I wonder where/why Pycharm would be using Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. I should have connected to:

```
C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

rather than:

```
C:\Users\i_am_yohan\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
```

I got confused because I was moving from Spyder to Pycharm and Spyder is connected to `pythonw.exe` rather than `python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error, after I uninstalled Python 3.6, which I did after installing Python 3.7. I was already using Python 3.7 through Pycharm successfully for a while, but realized after some time that I had Python 3.6 still installed, without using it. Doing the following fixed this for me.

Before trying anything else, you might want to check that you are using the expected Python interpreter for what you are trying to execute.

I don't know what exactly has changed that fixed this, and I wouldn't necessarily recommend this solution, since my understanding of what really happened is very limited. But it doesn't seem to have broken my project, and so maybe someone is helped by this.

I cut and pasted my `.idea` file from my project root folder. **Note that I cut and paste it, I didn't delete it.** Removing this folder makes you lose a many, if not all, of your Pycharm project's settings. So don't delete this folder unless you want to lose your project settings, like your run/debug configurations.

Then I restarted Pycharm, and it automically started to create a new `.idea folder` (which can be very time consuming). I closed Pycharm again, since I realized I didn't want to go through with this, I had too many settings that I didn't want to lose, and so I removed the **newly created** `.idea` folder, and put back the original `.idea` folder.

After starting up Pycharm again, all the time in the same project folder, Pycharm did have to do some indexing, but then it worked. The project I am working on is a Django project, and I have a run configuration for Django. The error was thrown when I wanted to run the Django configuration (Maybe I should have checked the interpreter is was set to before doing all this). The only thing I was required to do to after the swapping back and forth of the `.idea` folder was change the Python interpreter for the Django configuration, it seemed to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

This happends when python console wants to use Python 3.7 interpreter to connect to a project build based on previous version of python. Here is a quick solution if you have installed Python 3.7 correctlly.
Go to your Pycharm, find '**Switch project interpreter**' and change the  interpreter into the Python 3.7 version.